# Can't figure out the nested for loop part and how does it work in this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

I'm Trying to figure out this code that I found online. I don't understand how the nested loop actually provides the results in this specific tkinter program (four cases).
I used print statements in key parts in order to understand it, but the more I dive in the more confused I get.

Can someone please explain how the code works?

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root, use_geometry, show_buttons):
        fm = Frame(root, width=300, height=200, bg="blue")
        fm.pack(side=TOP, expand=NO, fill=NONE)

        if use_geometry:
            root.geometry("600x400") ### (1) Note geometry Window Manager method


        if show_buttons:
            Button(fm, text="Button 1", width=10).pack(side=LEFT)
            Button(fm, text="Button 2", width=10).pack(side=LEFT)
            Button(fm, text="Button 3", width=10).pack(side=LEFT)

case = 0
for use_geometry in (0, 1):
    for show_buttons in (0,1):
        case = case + 1
        root = Tk()
        root.wm_title("Case " + str(case)) ### (2) Note wm_title Window Manager method
        display = App(root, use_geometry, show_buttons)
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You want us to explain how the whole code works?

Comment: I need help with the nested loop part

Comment: @LittleWing See if my explanation in my answers your questions, otherwise I'm happy to explain.

Comment: The loops are just creating four different tkinter Apps, where each App takes a new root window and different values for use_geometry and show_buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly you're wondering how you can end up with our iterations with the following loop-statement.

```
for use_geometry in (0, 1):
    for show_buttons in (0,1):
```

Reason is that for both `use_geometry = 0` and `use_geometry = 1` we will run the inner loop resulting in the following four cases:

```
# First outer iteration, first inner
{ use_geometry = 0, show_buttons = 0 }

# First outer iteration, second inner
{ use_geometry = 0, show_buttons = 1 }

# Second outer iteration, first inner
{ use_geometry = 1, show_buttons = 0 }

# Second outer iteration, second inner
{ use_geometry = 1, show_buttons = 1 }

# Done
```

In total four combinations. For each of these four combinations you're creating a new `Tk()`and `App()`-instance, thus four instances in total.

Comment: So the nested loop passes a boolean result each time?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with boolean result but the code in the nested loop will be executed for each combination (in total 4 times) if that's what you're asking.